# Making a HasManyThrough relationship

Tags: laravel

I have 3 Models connected this way:

`Organization` → `ApplicationInstance` →(Pivot)→ `Invoice`

**Any idea how to get all Invoices from the Organization?**

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please [check out this guide about asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit yours accordingly, so others can help you with your problems. 
This questions is quite short, has very few specific details, and you are not quite presenting a problem, or any code that proves your efforts on solving the task.

Comment: So you want to make a simple question more complicated? What do anyone benefit from me writing the wrong code for doing this?

Comment: From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." Please, provide some code, show us the complete datamodell, describe why your efforts did not work, and describe the expected results. It is really hard to answer a generic question, that under the hood, is a specific problem. (just as below, where you mention you want the solution to be sorted, etc.)

Comment: Also, writing your "bad code" is quite the main thing to do here! Don't get me wrong, but we all learn from each other's mistakes, and it is always easier to help someone with their own code, then offer them the complete solution - and it benefits you more on the long run. How can we show you where you did a mistake? How can you get better at coding? Saying this as respectfully I can, I did not want to irritate you, but help you use this site better.

Comment: 1. Its not homework help 2. I cant post entire model code because that would reveal information about the project that i am not allowed to reveal according to my employment contract. 3. The model code is irrelevent i need help on how to use the HasManyThrough laravel function with a pivot table because i cannot find anything in the documentation about it. 4. What i do with the collection after i get it from the model is also irrelevent when im asking for help creating the relationship. 5. The worst thing you can do is clutter the questions with completely irrelevent information.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This is my solution to this problem:

```
    public function invoices() {

    $indexes = \DB::select('SELECT invoices.id FROM invoices,application_instance_invoice,application_instances
    WHERE invoices.id=application_instance_invoice.invoice_id
    AND application_instances.id=application_instance_invoice.application_instance_id
    AND application_instances.organization_id=:id', ['id' => $this->id]);

    $indexArray = array();

    foreach($indexes as $index) {
        array_push($indexArray,$index->id);
    }

    return Invoice::whereIn('id', $indexArray)->orderBy('created_at');
}
```

I am pretty sure there are easier ways to do this but this does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you have defined the [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships) on your models, then you can use `$organization->application_instance->invoice`.

Comment: Yes but i want to get all invoices and sort them by date before displaying them

Comment: Put all of your requirements in your question if you want to get a useful answer.

Comment: Its in the title that i want to make a relationship between the models.